# How to save an array of address?

Tags: solidity

I wrote a smart contract `PersonalInfo.sol`. In this smart contract, I want to save an array of address. Each address is the place where smart contract were deployed. However, each time I deployed the smart contract the array cleaned the history of address that it has been deployed and only push the address right now. How can I fix this issue? Please help.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract PersonalInfo{
    address public userAddress;
    address[] public Users;
    string public email;
    string public userName;


    function PersonalInfo ()public{
        userAddress = msg.sender;
        Users.push(userAddress);
    }
    function SavePersonalInfo(string Name, string Email)public{
        userName = Name;
        email = Email;
    }


}
```

Comment: i suggest you implement factory pattern where a factory contract will keep the addresses of each created contract. the described behaviour is normal aseach contract is deployed separatly and its constructor saves the senders address. otherwise you can creat a dedicated function which adds the personal infos or just rename the contract's name

Comment: @BadrBellaj Thanks for replying me. I don't know what is factory contract. Is that a style of writing smart contract or what? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: It's a design pattern where you'll have a contract that creates other instances. Read about the pattern and you'll understand how to use it on your case.

Answer (score 2):

Just for informative use around the question asked: you can create two smart-contracts.

- one that stores the data
- and another that has the elements that need to be stored.

Each time the second contract is deployed, the constructor parameters can be saved in the first contract.

**First Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract StorageContract{

    struct User {
        string email;
        string userName;
    }

    mapping(address=>User) mappingToUser;

    address[] public ContractsAdresses;

    function savePersonalInfo(string Name, string Email, address Addr) public {
        mappingToUser[Addr].email = Email;
        mappingToUser[Addr].userName = Name;
        ContractsAdresses.push(Addr);
    }
}
```

**Second Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
import "./StorageContract.sol";

contract PersonalInfo{

    address storageContractAddr = "Here goes your StorageContract address already deployed";

    function PersonalInfo(string Name, string Email) public{
        StorageContract s = StorageContract(storageContractAddr);
        s.savePersonalInfo(Name, Email, this);
    }
}
```

But as Lauri Peltonen tells you, you probably shouldn't deploy a new contract for each user. Doesn't seem like a very logical thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you deploy a contract its state is empty. You can do some pre-population of state in the contract's constructor but typically most of the data is populated in different functions.

Basically you shouldn't redeploy a contract once it's used. You should separate contract concerns into different contract so you can easily upgrade one of the contract while the other contract still retains its data (state). So the contract which gets redeployed has only a reference to the other contract which acts as a data storage contract. So something like `StorageContract contr = StorageContract(address);`.

In general you probably shouldn't deploy a new contract for each user. You should simply use a function which saves a user address with some logic. In your example you will never have more than one address in the array as constructor is only run once.